# Jennkins not able to connect AWS Account

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins file to deploy my application into EKS cluster. From jenkins side i installed AWS credential plugin and I added Jenkins credential my secret key and access key values into the box.

[image: Aws credential configuration]

Next when I'm running Jenkins build deployment stage falling with below error .

```
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.
```

Comment: looks like you still need the aws cli app on your jenkins box.
however to keep your jenkins box clean you might want to call it via docker https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-docker.html

Comment: yes i have aws cli app inside my jenkins. and coker version 20.10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue and found it was a PATH settings issue. Basically aws is not found in PATH . What you could do is add "env" to the code and see what PATH values are in console output. To set the PATH correctly

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables: name=PATH, value= (Ex: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/ )